# Chkeditor text/background colorbox not visible in bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to use chkeditor as text editor on bootstrap modal dialog. I am having issues with all the buttons which opens a dialog, colorbox or select combo.

I have fixed the issue for `link` dialogs by changing the z-index value of `cke_dialog` and `cke_dialog_background_cover` and it works good but I could not find a proper solution for color boxes, on looking at the source I found `cke_colorbox` and `cke_colorauto` for it but changing z-index doesn't seem to work and there's not much I could find fix this issue.

attaching 2 screen shots here

1. text editor color box on page (outside modal)
   [image]
2. text editor color box inside bootstrap modal (hidden by dialog box!)
   [image]

thanks for the help..

Comment: So the text box is on top of the drop down that the user chooses?

Comment: not the textbox but the bootstrap dialog is and even changing z-index isn't working

Comment: it sounds like a problem in the bootstrap it may be stealing focus you may need to override something within the bootstrap

Comment: well tried couple of things with both css and js but nothing worked yet! I'm still looking but you are right, bootstrap is stealing focus somehow!

Comment: maybe try `$.noop()` this may help or check if you are giving the modal element a position of absolute and so on?

Comment: Keep me updated on this i would like to find a solve :)